# Create svn repository from existing module, keeping history

Tags: svn

I have a legacy project under SVN organized as follows:

```
Legacy-Repository/trunk/
  |- module1
  |- module2
  |- ...
  '- moduleN
```

This legacy design does not match our needs, I need to create a SVN repository for each module while keeping each module's history) in order to obtain the following structure:

```
New-Repository1/trunk/ (content of module1's directory)
New-Repository2/trunk/ (content of module2's directory)
...
New-RepositoryN/trunk/ (content of moduleN's directory)
```

After this migration, the repository "Legacy-Repository" will be archived. Content in "Legacy-Repository/trunk/" that is not in a module is not important and does not need to be migrated.

What's the (best) way to achieve this (using svn command line) ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Note: I'm using svn 1.7.14.

Comment: Is `/trunk/moduleXXX` path to your module's root in LEGACY (not obvoius from your diagram)?

Comment: Yes, it is. All modules are in 'trunk'

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to go at it would be to use the [svndumpfilter](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svndumpfilter.html) command.

Basically, you need to dump your entire repository (using [svnadmin dump](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.dump.html) command) and filter the dump to generate one dump per module. Then, you can load each dump in new SVN repositories using `svnadmin load`.

Here is an example of `svndumpfilter` (fullSvnDump.dmp is the full repository dump):

```
svndumpfilter include trunk/module1 --drop-empty-revs --renumber-revs < fullSvnDump.dmp > module1.dmp 2> svndump.log &
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Somebody downvoted you but with no explanation and no alternative solution... :-/

Comment: @LazyBadger I could say the same of your comment...
Do you have a better way to answer @kraal's question? Do you know I have actually used this solution to do pretty much what OP what asking, and that it worked fine. My post may have been more complete with examples of `svnadmin dump` and `svnadmin load` but the use of these command is really straight-forward (command name + repo URL)...

That's not really a friendly way to greet new contributors...

Comment: @AlexRNL - Je ne suis pas louis d'or d'être aimé par tout le monde

Comment: Having tried this method for generating dumps, it works, but svnrdump is indeed simpler. Concerning the load part, @lazy badger's method also requires svnadmin command in order to use --ignore-uuid. All in all I see no valid reason for having downvoted this answer (and thus I give it a +1)... While not being the best one, it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

**Сlaims to shortcomings of Alex's answer**

- `svnrdump dump URL/TO/Module` instead of `svnadnin dump | svndumpfilter include` is 1) shorter 2) doesn't require full access to server
- `svnadmin load` does not and can not change path to the restored dump, only change "mount-point" to custom location with `--parent-dir` option, thus: tree, dumped as `trunk/ModuleN` will appear after restoring to root of new separate repo also as `trunk/ModuleN`, not as requested `/`

**Polished solutions and ideas**

- Dump every subtree with `svnrdump dump` (faster, less wasted space)
- If "dirty" history doesn't annoy you -  don't forget immediately after loading dump into new repository (don't forget at least `--ignore-uuid` option in order to prevent sharing UUID between all new repos) `svn mv` trunk/ModuleN to the /
- If you want clean history - you can try to "hack" dumps before loading (get proper path inside repo), using [SVN-DumpReloc](http://search.cpan.org/~salva/SVN-DumpReloc-0.02/bin/svn-dump-reloc) perl-script (not tested)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try to do it this way and will give you a feedback.

Comment: svnrdump works fine, however, SVN-DumpReloc is not usable as is. Indeed it relies on dump stream format v2, and the version of svnrdump I'm using produces v3 dumps. I'll have to find another way to "relocate" the code (probably sed should do the job)

Comment: @kraal - remove version-check from code or replace version to 3 in `$head =~ /^SVN-fs-dump-format-version:\s*2\s*$/`

Comment: I'm facing another problem: when I do a ``svnrdump dump https://.../branches/MyBranch/module1/ > module1.dump`` and then do a ``grep -a Node-path module1.dump``, I see that the dump contains files whose Node-path is ``.../MyBranch/module2/``, in other words it doesn't seem to limit the dump to the directory I'm specifying (svnrdump version: 1.7.14)

Comment: @kraal - only if **you touched files** in the *both modules* in some revision: none of mentioned tools split revisions, because revision is atomic operation, not per-file|directory action