# Moving a svn repo without breaking branches

Tags: svn, merge

I am consolidating several SVN repositories into one using the method described here: [Combining multiple SVN repositories into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267256/combining-multiple-svn-repositories-into-one)

eg.

- `svnadmin dump /repo > repo.dmp`
- `svnadmin load --parent-dir /imported/repo /newrepo < repo.dmp`

I then use svn rename to move the trunk of the imported repo into a more appropriate location in my composite repository

eg.

`svn rename /imported/repo/Trunk /Trunk/somefolder`

However if i merge from an imported branch into the new location I get a tree conflict because what used to be the trunk has been moved.

eg.

`svn merge /imported/repo/Branches/a-branch /Trunk/somefolder`

**Is there a better way to import/move/merge repositories that avoids getting a tree conflict here?**

Comment: You might want to try using the `--ignore-ancestry` option when merging. Is the tree conflict really due to relocating the trunk? What if you try to merge the branch before relocating the trunk?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34084680/create-svn-repository-from-existing-module-keeping-history for ideas

Comment: I have tried merging again and it seemed to work sensibly (no idea why it was conflicting yesterday) but maybe i was seeing something that wasn't there or attributing it to the move when I did something else weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I don't think `svn mv` is the source of tree-conflict and yes, `--ignore-ancestry` may help with merge
- You can try to *avoid renaming* by using [svn-dump-reloc](http://search.cpan.org/~salva/SVN-DumpReloc-0.02/bin/svn-dump-reloc) on dump before loading it

Comment: `svn-dump-reloc` sounds promising. Its what i basically want to do anyway.